# PHP MySQL and Proper Development / Staging before sending to Production Server

Tags: php, mysql

I've just gotten my production site up and running.  I have a lot more work to do, and I'm realizing the need now for a development server before pushing changing live onto the production site (with users) - obviously...

This thread (and a lot more on Stack) describe me:
[Best/Better/Optimal way to setup a Staging/Development server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990812/php-best-better-optimal-way-to-setup-a-staging-development-server)

Anyhow...  Reading these threads is outright confusing at times, with all of the thrown around terminology, and my smaller CentOS/Apache knowledge.

My goal is to:

1. Make some changes to files as needed.
2. Test the changes *on the same server, to ensure settings are identical*.
3. If all is ok, I can now save a version of this somewhere, perhaps locally is enough for now (Bazaar seems like a possibility?)
4. Finally, replace all of the changed files via SSH or SFTP or something...

My worries are:

- Uploading changes while users are in the system.
- How to upload the files that have changed, only.

I'd love somebody to either link to a great guide for what I'm thinking about (that leaves nothing to imagination I'd hope) - or some kind of suggestion/etc...  I'm running in circles trying out different SVN's and progarms to manager them, etc...

I'm the only one developing, and just want a repeatable, trust-worthy solution that can work for me without making my life too miserable trying to get it set up (and keep it set up).

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everyone for the tips/hints/etc...

I've finally found the perfect solution for my needs, SpringLoops...  http://www.springloops.com/v2/

It manages my SVN (which I use Tortoise SVN with) - and will actually deploy the changes onto my two sites:  staging and production.

I highly recommend it, it's working wonderfully so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you have the ability to create a staging subdomain on the production server, here is how I would (and do) handle it:

Develop on your development machine, storing your code in a VCS. I use subversion, but you may find another you prefer.  After making changes, you check in your code.

On your production server, you create a subdomain in an Apache VirtualHost which is identical to, but isolated from your production VirtualHost.  Checkout your code from the VCS to the staging subdomain area.  After making changes, you then run an update from your VCS, which pulls only changed files down.  Staging and production share the same data set, or you may have a separate database for each.

The reason for using a subdomain instead of just a different directory is that it enables you to use the same DocumentRoot for both staging and production.  It's also easy to identify where you are if you use something like `staging.example.com`.

When you're certain everything works as it's supposed to you can run a VCS update on the production side to bring the code up to date.

It is important to be sure that you have instructed Apache to forbid access to the VCS metadata directories (.svn, .git, whatever).

**Addendum**

To forbid access to `.svn` directories use a rewrite rule like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .*\.svn/.* - [F]
```

This will send a 403 on them.  You could also redirect them to the homepage to make it less obvious they're even present.

Comment: What SVN do you use specifically, and what desktop application to assist?  Also - how do I instruct Apache to forbid access to those directories?

Comment: @Shackrock I use plain old command line Subversion (svn) rather than any GUI because I develop on Linux. I have used TortoiseSVN on Windows and it's nice.  See above for Apache info.

Comment: ok so I just re-read your post... and there's some ability to create a staging site with an identical site path within apache?  Can you clue me in on where to start with that, perhaps some guides?  I don't understand how my /home/user/public_html could be the same...  I was planning on just pointing a subdomain to another folder, but it sounds like your method is better if I can figure it out...  Thanks!

Comment: @Shackrock Not a staging area in an identical path, I meant a virtualhost pointed to another directory so staging & prod both `DocumentRoot` at `/`. You're right to just point subdomain to another folder.

Comment: gotcha... ok so, I thought I could use CNAME to point a subdomain to another folder (which would act as its root) - but I can't figure it out... clue me in? haha.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of worry #1, remember that even StackOverflow periodically goes down for maintenance when people are using it.  Just provide a good mechanism for you to switch the site to maintenance mode (and back out) and you'll be fine.

Comment: Good call...  So, are there tools or guides that teach how to properly bring a server down for update, and then back up afterwards?

Comment: Since you're using Apache, just create a mod_rewrite rule in your .htaccess file that redirects all request to a maintenance page. `RewriteRule ^ maintenance.html [L]`. Your mechanism for switching the site into and out of maintenance mode will be changing a single character in your .htaccess file -- a # to comment out the line or uncomment it.

Comment: Or, perhaps if you have a database with an admin panel of some sort, have a database table that controls whether you're in or out of maintenance mode, so you can push a button to control it.

Answer (score 0):

You need a version control system, like Subversion, Git or Mercurial.

When you change files, you commit those changes to a repository. This keeps track of all the changes you've made and lets you undo them if it turns out you did something stupid. It also lets you restore files you accidentally delete or lose.

On top of that, it makes deploying updates as simple as typing 'git update' or 'svn update' on the production server. Only the files that changed get transferred and put in place.

You will get this advice no matter how many times the question is re-asked. You need version control.

Comment: Understood.  I do like version control, from what I've tried.  What I don't understand completely is how to link my control from my local machine(s) that I develop on locally, to the server test environment (that command 'svn update' can't just "work," so I am in search for a guide on setting it up properly) - and then once tested, pushing it to the production site, which is live...

Comment: To create working directory, which is just somewhere on a computer where a copy of a repository lives and you can use the subversion commands, you "svn checkout [repo url]". Run that command on your home computer, on your staging/testing computer, and on your production computer. There will be a working directory on all of them. You can make changes and type "svn commit" to save them from any of those directories. You can run "svn update" to get the latest version of all files from any of those directories. It "just works".

Comment: ahhhh, it does sound cool...  So, I have to ask again though - is there a guide for "first time setup" of these with windows as my local machine and CentOS as my server(both test and production), that you know of?

Comment: If you have a few bucks a month, you'll save yourself a lot of trouble by letting someone else create and host the repositories. Springloops, CVSDude, Github are examples of companies that offer that service. In Windows, use TortoiseSVN if you want a GUI. It integrates into Windows Explorer so you just right click in any directory and have buttons like "SVN checkout" and "SVN Update" right there. There are [good books, too](http://www.amazon.com/Pragmatic-Version-Control-Subversion-Starter/dp/0977616657/ref=tmm_pap_title_0).

Comment: Beautiful.  SNV vs. GIT, thoughts?

Comment: I prefer subversion when I'm working alone and git when working with others.